# Binding on Windows Phone 7 does not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding, windows-phone-8

I have a strange binding problem on WP 7. Code works on WP8 without problems but when I run the same (following) code on WP7 binding does not work and TextBlock.Text is "". Here is the code (binding is set on the Text property of the second TextBlock):

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,35">
        <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">

            <StackPanel x:Name="MeasurementUnitPropertyPanel" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Margin="12,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" MinHeight="100">
                <TextBlock x:Name="MeasurementUnitPropertyLabel" Width="235" Margin="0,30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=AppResources.MeasurementUnitPropertyLabel, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" FontSize="28">
                    <TextBlock.Foreground>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </TextBlock.Foreground>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="MeasurementUnitPropertyValue" Width="185" Margin="0,30,0,0" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding MeasurementUnit}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" FontSize="28">
                    <TextBlock.Foreground>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource DarkGrayThemeColor}"/>
                    </TextBlock.Foreground>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
```

...

Then I set the DataContext in the OnNavigatedTo method (or in the constructor, problem is the same)...

```
// When page is navigated to set data context to selected item in list
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel = new ClimateSettingsViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
        //MeasurementUnitPropertyValue.DataContext = viewModel.MeasurementUnit; //This does not work too...

        //Other stuff...
    }
```

(part of) ClimateSettingsViewModel class:

```
class ClimateSettingsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public String MeasurementUnit
    {
        get
        {
            return ClimateSettings.MeasurementUnitValues[App.UserData.SelectedConfiguration.ClimateSettings.MeasurementUnit];
        }
        /*
        set
        {
            if (value != ClimateSettings.MeasurementUnitValues[App.UserData.SelectedConfiguration.ClimateSettings.MeasurementUnit])
            {
                App.UserData.SelectedConfiguration.ClimateSettings.MeasurementUnit = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MeasurementUnit");
            }
        }*/
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

App platform is WP OS 7.1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: put break point on ClimateSettings.MeasurementUnitValues[App.UserData.SelectedConfiguration.ClimateSettings.MeasurementUnit];" line and check whether it is coming on this line and also check the value of MeasurementUnit after the execution of this line(use f10) and update what you getting

Comment: I am not sure if it is a copy/paste typo, but I am sure you meant `*public* class ClimateSettingsViewModel`? It makes all the difference in the world :)

Comment: As Toni Petrina told, the problem is that your viewmodel class is not marked as public. While Wp8 Binding system can bind to viewmodels not declared as public, wp7 needs it to be public.

Comment: Breakpoint is never reached (on WP7) but TextBlock.DataContext is set properly. The problem is that TextBlock.Text property is "" even if MeasurementUnit is "°F"...

Comment: Turn on all exceptions ;)

Comment: Set ClimateSettingsViewModel to public works! Thank you! Strange problem because this code works properly on WP8! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8 have differently implemented reflection.

On Windows Phone 7, if you try to access private or internal functions, you will get a `MethodAccessException` but on the Windows Phone 8 it will just work.

Just turn on all exceptions when debugging and this error will jump up.